# Loading big part of the graph in a single traversal/query

Tags: titan, gremlin

I would like to load a bigger part of a graph with one query/traversal (in order to save network requests).

So what I would like to do:

1. One traversal
2. Retrieve a big part of a graph.
3. Start from a given Vertex (by id normally)
4. In tree format (for processing afterwards)
5. Include edges (for processing afterwards)
6. Process the data afterwards to put it into a data structure.

For example in the graph below I would like to get everything starting from "hercules". But I do not want the "lives" edge and the data going out there.

So far I got this:

```
GraphTraversal traversal = titanGraph.traversal()
    .V().has("name", "hercules").as("v").outE("battled").as("e").inV().tree();

traversal.next();
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [thinkaurelius.com](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/images/graph-of-the-gods-2.png))</sub>

Comment: What's it exactly that isn't working?

Comment: So based on my understanding you want to load all edges and their vertices except edges with label `lives`? If so, you could change `outE("battled")` step to include all other edges you want. should be similar to `outE("battled", "mother", "father")` and add more edge labels as you need. Does that help?